How to have the UUIDs consistent across all the HTTP requests under the same thread group using JSR223 preprocessor
I have a jmx script which is being used for doing some load/performance testing on our application.
In this process what is happening is we have three API calls (HTTP request) where there is a consistent two parameters ${event_id} and ${obs_id} added in the request body.
Now i am trying to use JSR223 preprocessor to generate the UUIDs for the above two parameters defined and would like it to generate new UUIDs for each progression as in if i am running it as number of threads=10 then it should generate 10 UUIDs each for the above parameter individually to mimic 10 users.
test plan
test plan 2
the HTTP requests are under the Test transaction controller.
Here is the groovy script i am using to generate UUIDs for the above parameters,
vars.put("event_id", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
vars.put("obs_id}", UUID.randomUUID().toString())

JSR223 preprocessor
but whats happening for me is, its generating new UUIDs for each parameter in different HTTP requests and not staying consistent across all the http request within the same thread group.
On the first HTTP request's body, the event_id is 5e9f32dd-39a9-469d-be10-0688627eae48, the second request 06d36644-ecd7-411d-a37e-abfe240cde25 and third request 9ad6563b-cf59-4591-8a2d-37eae9ad7b5a
similarly for the obs_id its generated 91bbcdeb-794a-48dd-a6d6-ac11a24dbd82
on the debug sampler, the JMeterVariable shows,
obs_id=91ce63da-5d2e-4054-97e7-5cd6b29f3fe9
event_id=88021da1-9f7c-41a8-8737-1bb9968d84c2

so its new UUIDs everywhere and not consistent across all the HTTP requests

UUIDs are, for practical purposes, unique, so I am not getting your question...

i would like to repeat the generated UUID stored as a value to a key, in my case for example for key obs_id i would like the value to be consistent across all the HTTP requests. if the UUID generated is 91bbcdeb-794a-48dd-a6d6-ac11a24dbd82 for key obs_id i would like it to be consistent and same in other HTTP requests body within the same thread group.

you could store it somewhere, and re-use it ?

its a huge task in my case when i need to run it for 50 threads (users) where i will have to place them under the user defined variables with 50 different UUIDs? since that particular UUIDs is stored in the DB then cant reuse same as i would stumble upon error.

According to JMeter Scoping Rules the JSR223 PreProcessor is being executed before each Sampler in its scope therefore you're getting a new value each time the PreProcessor is being executed.
Put the PreProcessor as a child of the first request and you should see the same value for the current iteration for all requests.
If you want the same value for the subsequent iterations as well - put your expression under if condition like
if (vars.getIteration() == 1) {
    vars.put("event_id", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
    vars.put("obs_id}", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
}

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?

i tried this but did not work. when i tried your suggestion, now the UUID is generated only once and its going blank in the other HTTP requests and not replacing the defined keys in the request body.

It's hard to guess what's wrong without seeing your test plan

i have added test plan 2 image to see the test plan, let me know if anything else is needed
